# How to get function self reference from within that function?

Tags: javascript

is there any way to get function reference when i'm inside function?

```
var arrayOfFunction = [ myFunction ];

arrayOfFunction[0]();

function myFunction() {
    removeFromArray( thisFunctionReference ) // how to get function self reference here?
};

function removeFromArray(functionRef) {
    index = arrayOfFunction.indexOf(functionRef);
    if (index > -1) {
        arrayOfFunction.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just `removeFromArray(myFunction)`?

Comment: Fix the typo (`function myFunction () {...}`) and use the name of the function to refer the function itself.

Comment: @Teemu right, fixed.

Comment: As I understand there's no magic alternative like 'this' keyword? I'm mean something that is function name independent.

Comment: Correct, `this` refers to an object, not a function, functions don't have any magic referencing system, only their name, or the function literal itself. Also, unless the code is not too much simplified, you don't need the self-reference in `myFunction`, just call it in `removeFromArray` function.

Comment: Well code is simplified. Thanks for your help! Your solution is so obvious...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript, functions are first class members and thus behave like any other object. You can just refer to it by name like this:

```js
myFunction.property = 5;

function myFunction() {
  console.log(myFunction.property) //logs 5
  console.log(myFunction) // logs the function 
};

myFunction();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do following as well

```
removeFromArray(arguments.callee);
```

Whether you should do that or not will depend on whether you are planning to use "strict" mode in your app.  [More info in documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee).